# Youtube API Consumption & Caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.1, youtube-api

I am consuming youtube API using [youtube_it gem](https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it).And this gem uses [Faraday gem](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) as an adapter instead of using Net::http directly. As you already know making a such remote request takes atleast couple of seconds? Now since i don't have direct access to **Net::http** library , how would i implement caching in my app?Here is the sample request that fetch videos from youtube.

```
      #Authentication
     $ @client = YouTubeIt::OAuth2Client.new(client_access_token: "access_token", client_refresh_token: "refresh_token", client_id: "client_id", client_secret: "client_secret", dev_key: "dev_key", expires_at: "expiration time")

        #Request
      @videos= @client.videos_by(:query => "penguin").videos #=>returns array of videos
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this using [Memcache](https://github.com/evan/memcached), keying off a combination of the query and penguin. You have to do a bit more legwork yourself, but I've found that it's usually better for me to write my own caching because caching can lead to a ton of bugs when you turn it on too early.

Here's what your code might do:

1. Check for @videos in your cache. Keyed by a concatenation of access token and query.
2. If there's a cache miss, do the fetch and store the results in the cache.
3. If there's a cache hit, return what's in the cache. Deserialize, and store it in @videos

One quick question: is there a reason you are making @client an instance variable? You probably are doing this in a controller and don't need this in the view, so as a general principle you should limit the scope of what is available to your views.